# GoogleマップのData Layerにjsのオブジェクトを直接渡す方法を探しています

Tags: javascript, bitmap, google-maps

## Google Maps JavaScript API v3 を使用し、webサイトに地図を描画しデータに応じて地図を修飾しようとしています.

その際に、表題でも述べましたがDataLayerにjsのオブジェクトを直接渡して地図のデコレートを行ないたいと思っているのですが、

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer

この辺りを調べた限り、↓の様にデコレートの度にjsonを取得する方法しか今の所見つけられていません.

```
map.data.loadGeoJson('https://example/a.json');
map.data.loadGeoJson('https://example/b.json');
```

地図のデコレートの度に通信が飛ぶ事を避けたく、取得したjsのオブジェクト（Json）を変数に格納して漸進的に描画＋その値を使い回す方法を探しています.

↓やりたい事のイメージはこんな感じです.

```
$.get 'https://example/a.json', function(data) {
  map.data.何か(data.key1);
  console.log(data.key2);
  map.data.何か(data.key3);
};
```

よろしくお願い致します.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

こんにちは

地図の装飾の処理内容によりますが、 [`addfeature`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data.AddFeatureEvent) イベントが使えそうな気がします。

```
map.data.addListener('addfeature', function(event) {
    // 何かする
    event.feature....
});
```

コールバック関数の引数である `event` 変数には [`AddFeatureEvent`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data.AddFeatureEvent) オブジェクトが来ます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！！こちらの方法で上手くいきました！

Comment: @GogoTanaka おめでとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

解決されたようですが、他にも方法があります。

1. loadGeoJson には 第3引数があり、    ここに function(array_of_features) を設定できます。 この functionの中で ローカル変数に貯めておいて、随時 add/remove すればOKです。これが通常の方法かと思います。

   ```
   var myFeatures = [];

   //...

   if (myFeatures.length === 0) {
       map.data.loadGeoJson('some.geojson', {}, function (arrf) {
           arrf.forEach(function(one) {
               myFeatures.push(one);
           });
       });
   } else {
       myFeatures.forEach(function(one) {
           map.data.add(one);
       });
   }
   ```
2. google maps api が "properで"(="標準機能として")実装される前の geoJson用コードを    使えば お望みのことがそのままできます。
3. geoJsonでなく、topoJsonを使う場合は、$.getJson を使った方法で実装できます。https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki

   ```
   $.getJSON('some.topojson', function (data) {
           var geoJsonObject = topojson.feature(data, data.objects['some']);
            //geoJsonObject を使って何かする
   });
   ```

Comment: 「properで実装される前」という文が気になったのですが、この proper とは何かの固有名詞でしょうか？

Comment: ごめんなさい。「標準機能として実装される」という意味で書きました。修正しておきました。